# Laravel 8 - Save multiple checkbox selections with separate field to pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

**Background:**

Laravel 8 + Bootstrap 5

I'm pulling a list of licence categories from database to the form.

In the form user is asked to tick which licence to assign to the user. (up to that point I'm OK)

**Target**

I'd like licence expiry date to be assigned to every category selected.

**Code**

*blade.php*

```
<div class="mb-1"><strong>Assign user's driving licence categories:</strong></div>
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-text" style="width: 6ch !important;">{{$category->name}}</div>
      <div class="input-group-text">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{{$category->id}}">
      </div>
   <div class="input-group-text">Expiry date</div>
      <input class="form-control" type="date" name="expiry_date[]">
   </div>
@endforeach
```

[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq0ob.png)

*pivot table migration*

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('driving_licence_category_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('driving_licence_category_id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('expiry_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

*models*

User

```
    public function drivingLicenceCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\DrivingLicenceCategory')
        ->withPivot('expiry_date')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Licence

```
    public function userHasDrivingLicenceCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
```

*UserController*

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'roles' => 'required',
            'categories' => 'required',
            'expiry_date' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = User::create($request->except(['roles', 'categories', 'expiry_date']))
            ->syncRoles($request->roles)
            ->drivingLicenceCategory()->sync($request->only('categories'));

            //missing code to store the expiry_date information

        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'User added successfully.');
    }
```

Thank you for spending time on this post :)

Comment: use updateExistingPivot() https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table

Comment: I could use `$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);` but how to retrieve input request for each checkbox and put it into that code??